# Unable to read memory after allocate from a function which referenced in main function

Tags: c, malloc, access-violation

I have a function which is called `get_audio_signal()`. This function is called in main `thread`.
This is main file and main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "record.h"


/*******************************************************************/
int main(void);
int main(void)
{
    SAMPLE *tmp = get_audio_signal();
    free(tmp);
    return 1;
}
```

`get_audio_signal` was declared in `record.h`. Here is `get_audio_signal()` function:

```
SAMPLE* get_audio_signal()
    {
    PaStreamParameters inputParameters, outputParameters;
    PaStream *stream;
    PaError err;
    SAMPLE *recordedSamples;
    int i;
    int totalFrames;
    int numSamples;
    int numBytes;
    SAMPLE max, average, val;


    printf("patest_read_record.c\n"); fflush(stdout);

    totalFrames = NUM_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE; /* Record for a few seconds. */
    numSamples = totalFrames * NUM_CHANNELS;

    numBytes = numSamples * sizeof(SAMPLE);
    recordedSamples = (SAMPLE *)malloc(numBytes);
    if (recordedSamples == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //printf("%f ", *recordedSamples);
    for (i = 0; i<numSamples; i++) recordedSamples[i] = 0;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if (err != paNoError) goto error;

    inputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice(); /* default input 
device */
    if (inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No default input device.\n");
        goto error;
    }
    inputParameters.channelCount = NUM_CHANNELS;
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = 
    Pa_GetDeviceInfo(inputParameters.device)->defaultLowInputLatency;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

/* Record some audio. -------------------------------------------- */
    err = Pa_OpenStream(
        &stream,
        &inputParameters,
        NULL,                  /* &outputParameters, */
        SAMPLE_RATE,
        FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
        paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't 
bother clipping them */
        NULL, /* no callback, use blocking API */
        NULL); /* no callback, so no callback userData */
    if (err != paNoError) goto error;

    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError) goto error;
    printf("Now recording!!\n"); fflush(stdout);

    err = Pa_ReadStream(stream, recordedSamples, totalFrames);
    if (err != paNoError) goto error;

    err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError) goto error;
    return recordedSamples;

error:
    Pa_Terminate();
    fprintf(stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
    return -1;
}
```

My issue is, when i allocate for `recordedSamples` by using `malloc` then `recoredSamples` is unable to read memory. Hence, it make my assignment for `recordedSamples` crash. The error return is `"Access violation writing location"`. 
Here is the path that made the program crashed:

```
    recordedSamples = (SAMPLE *)malloc(numBytes);
    if (recordedSamples == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //printf("%f ", *recordedSamples);
    for (i = 0; i<numSamples; i++) recordedSamples[i] = 0;
```

Here is constant define.

```
#define SAMPLE_RATE  (16000)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER (1024)
#define NUM_SECONDS     (5)
#define NUM_CHANNELS    (1)

#define DITHER_FLAG     (0) /**/

#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paFloat32
typedef float SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0.0f)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%.8f"
```

Can anyone explain for me!!!

Comment: What is the value of `numBytes` ? What is the value of `NUM_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE` ? What is the value of `NUM_CHANNELS` ?

Comment: sorry, i will declare it in edit.

Comment: i've already checked all parameters. they're all right. Hence, i don't know why that path made my program crashed. Help me

Comment: when i place get_audio_signal() function at main file. It worked. But when i clip this function and place it at record.c and define in record.h. It will crash as i described above

Comment: [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJIw71srQ) works. What compiler are you using? Are you aware that INT_MAX is **at least** 16768 , and you are assigning the value of 320000 to it? Is in your system sizeof(int) == 4?  Maybe use `size_t` type like you are supposed to when representing the size of an object?

Comment: You sure your error is in that code then? With the debugger connected compiled with debugging symbols and no optimisition, you should be able to get the exact line of the crash.

Comment: i'm using msvc. Not gcc. I doubt that it's a point

Comment: yeah, i'm sure about that, because, i debugged too many times. Malloc works fine, but when i access to write value to each elements, it's get error

Comment: i used size_t to test, the issue still remain. I dont know why

Comment: Let's try creating the smallest example in which the issue persists. I mean, what if you remove all the portaudio functions then? Can you get the value of `i` where the access violation happens?

Comment: yeah, i tried. And the issue still remain. Here is what i do:

    SAMPLE* x = get_tmp();

    SAMPLE * get_tmp()
    {
     SAMPLE *tmp = (SAMPLE *)malloc(sizeof(SAMPLE) * 10);
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
     {
      tmp[i] = 0;
     }
     return tmp;
    }

Comment: get_tmp() function i placed in record.c and defined in record.h. Remember that, when i place get_tmp() function in main file. It works

Comment: i'm using msvc 2017, window sdk 10.0.17134.0. And this issue occurs in another computer which built my program. Hence, i don't think it's about my device

Comment: oh sorry, i've checked it out. In msvc, malloc was defined in stdlib.h. And i forgot to include it in record.h. But i don't know why the malloc didnt return NULL. Anyway, thank you mr Cuk

Comment: Och, ok. Always inspect the compilation warnings. In case no forward declaration of a function exists C the compiler implicitly guesses that is has the type of `int`. So the compiler "thought" that is was `int malloc(int)` and handled malloc incorrectly.

Comment: oh, thank you for the explanation!!!